# Delayed receiving the email message using the SMTP server

Tags: email, iis, smtp, smtpclient

I already deployed the Email Service I developed on the Chicago Server. Last Friday 11:30pm in Philippine time, I tested the sending and it run's properly, but when I checked my email there's no message in inbox or spam. And then, Saturday 1:30am, I've noticed that I received the message that I tested last Friday.

Please advice me guys! thanks!

My Questions is:

a.) Do I need to configure something on the Server to make the real time receiving on emails?

here's my code:

```
 //send email
MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailAdd"].ToString()), new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailAdd"].ToString()));
objEmail.Subject = "Test";
objEmail.Body = "CODE:" + _Message;
objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
SmtpMail.Host = "localhost";
SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
```

Comment: Post it over on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this one on your code:

`SmtpMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;`

And also, configure the relay restrictions on the SMTP server that will allow your 120.0.0.1/localhost..

Last, configure the firewall and port forwarding on the server.

I hope this will help you..